# How to add forms to formset Dinamically on browsable django Rest API?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to add multiple forms dynamically in django rest API. Just like we do in django admin. we use modelforset and we dynamically add those formset with AJAX. i want to do the same in API.[This image is the sample representation i need in API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkcPE.png) Thank You

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms don't support the nested representation - also known as formsets in Django - yet. This is work in progress and will come at some point later.
For now, your option is to use a javascript to send data as json.

Answer (score 0):

have a add button to insert a new row ,you have the clone the previous row and update the new form element id's and increment total_form_count value

Comment: that i have done on...but i want to do same in in browsable Rest API.